# How to preview an image using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

The code given below is displaying an image in browser using PHP  script,

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("phplogo.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I want that a user select image from his computer and then it is displayed in the browser using php? How to do that?

Comment: You need to upload Image if you want to do it by PHP. else, you can show it by javascript

Comment: means there is no way?

Comment: There is way, but you need to upload the image first by Ajax or by PHP post then you can display it.

Comment: how can you write code for me?

Comment: Do you still want to be done with PHP only, because Jquery and CSS are quite good approaches to achieve it?

Comment: no After displaying image using jquery, how to pass image variable to controller which there will be flipped and displayed to the same page?

Comment: You can flip the image by CSS, Do you want to flip the physical image? then I would suggest the different way.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by javascript/jquery rather than PHP if you do not want to upload it before the preview.

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
<style>
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have to apply flip function on it in controller how to do that then?

Comment: You can do it by CSS. Updated the code. Just hover the image after selection, you will get the flip

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

How to preview & upload an image by Jquery.

```js
function showPreview(objFileInput) {
  if (objFileInput.files[0]) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $("#targetLayer").html('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="200px" height="200px" class="upload-preview" />');
      $("#targetLayer").css('opacity', '0.7');
      $(".icon-choose-image").css('opacity', '0.5');
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(objFileInput.files[0]);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#uploadForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData(this),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#body-overlay").show();
      },
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#targetLayer").html(data);
        $("#targetLayer").css('opacity', '1');
        setInterval(function() {
          $("#body-overlay").hide();
        }, 500);
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }));
});
```

```html
<div id="body-overlay">
  <div><img src="loading.gif" width="64px" height="64px" /></div>
</div>
<div class="bgColor">
  <form id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <div id="targetOuter">
      <div id="targetLayer"></div>
      <img src="photo.png" class="icon-choose-image" />
      <div class="icon-choose-image">
        <input name="userImage" id="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" onChange="showPreview(this);" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" class="btnSubmit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can check the  the [demo](https://phppot.com/demo/jquery-ajax-image-upload/) and [download](https://phppot.com/demo/jquery-ajax-image-upload/jquery-ajax-image-upload.zip).

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?